# A word that is the study of heirarchies of information

Tags: single-word-requests

What would be the study of hierarchies of information?

We have meetings where we discuss this and need a word to characterize them. Like building trees of information and relationship. Something like ontology or phylogeny but for this specific use.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might consider using 'taxonomy'. Here's an example of the term in use:

> Information architects grapple with taxonomy, but developers often ignore it--to their own detriment. Understanding information taxonomy is the first step in designing better software from the ground up.

(From ["Understanding information taxonomy helps build better apps"](http://www.techrepublic.com/article/understanding-information-taxonomy-helps-build-better-apps/) at *TechRepublic*, June 25, 2003.)

As observed later in the same article, 'taxonomy' is *hierarchical*:

> Taxonomy structure has the following key characteristics:
>
> - It is hierarchical. Similar to the classification systems illustrated in Listings A and B, taxonomy structure is multilevel, representing hierarchical relationships between concepts within a defined scope and context.

Comment: this is very good (and taxonomy is the word I was struggling to remember). It's interesting to read this Wikiepedia article https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ontology_(information_science) and realize that ontology is being used (very) incorrectly when building these heirarchies and that a taxonomy would be closer in true meaning.